# How to make class iterable with foreach?

Tags: java

I have this class:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Polynomial<T> implements Iterable<T>  {
    Map<Integer, Object> polynomial;

    public Polynomial(){
        polynomial = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
    }
    public  Polynomial(int numberOfMembers){
        polynomial = new HashMap<Integer, Object>(numberOfMembers);
    }
    public void addElm(int power, int coefficient){
        if (power < 0) {
            power = Math.abs(power);
            throw new RuntimeException("ERROR: The power must be an absolute number, converting to absolute");
        }
        for (Map.Entry m : polynomial.entrySet()) {
            if ((Integer) m.getKey() == power){
                polynomial.put(power,m.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (Iterator<T>) new Object;
    }

}
```

And here is part of main function:

```
 Polynomial<Integer> p1=new Polynomial<Integer>();
 for (Integer r : p1)
 System.out.println(r.toString());
```

As you can see above I need to make foreach on Polynomial class, that's why Polynomial implement Iterable interface. But my problem that I don't know how to implement iterator() method. How can I do that?

Comment: What would you expect the iterator to give you? A sequence of map entries? Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: Please read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is very confusing. What is `T`? Why is `T` not used in the class? What is the `coefficient` parameter used for? What are you trying to do?

My best guess is that `T` is the type of coefficient of the polynomial, and you are trying to return an iterator that iterates through the coefficients.

I rewrote your code like this:

```
public class Polynomial<T> implements Iterable<T>  {
    Map<Integer, T> polynomial;

    public Polynomial(){
        polynomial = new HashMap<Integer, T>();
    }
    public  Polynomial(int numberOfMembers){
        polynomial = new HashMap<Integer, T>(numberOfMembers);
    }
    public void addElm(int power, T coefficient){
        if (power < 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("ERROR: The power must be an absolute number");
        }
        polynomial.put(power,coefficient);
    }
    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return polynomial.values().iterator();
    }

}
```

Comment: Of course this implementation is useless in practice as the iterator will not return the coefficients in any specified order, but we should leave it to OP to figure out how to solve that problem. :)